# Show input field's title tooltip on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

Not using any tooltip libraries except whats provided with jQuery by default.
jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/xZzQ9/
Have input field with tooltip that shows nicely on hover ..

```
Name:
<input type="text" id="name" title="Please input your name" />
<button id="start" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

jquery setup of tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).tooltip();
    $("#name").tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: "slideDown",
            delay: 250
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to programmically display that same tooltip when the button is clicked? e.g

```
$("#start").click(function () {
    //show tooltip
});
```

Comment: What jQuery tooltip plugin are you using? if any? And if not, why can't you do this in JavaScript? And can you also provide a JsFiddle?

Comment: have you tried the "e.g" code out?

Comment: @pferdefleisch the e.g does not show the tooltip

Comment: @DumbProducts provided jsfiddle

Comment: What? It does show the tooltip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: the tooltip shows if user hovers over the input field, but i want to show the tooltip if user clicks the button `#start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your example snippet follows the API of your tooltip library and from your question, I think that you want to not redirect on submit. If these two things are the case, this code **may** work

```
$('#start').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#name").tooltip({
    show: {
      effect: "slideDown",
      delay: 250
    }
  });
});
```

You are grabbing the event object that gets sent in as the first argument to jQuery event functions and stopping it from submitting the page and redirecting, the default action.
I hope this is what you meant.

You will have to handle that submit now all by yourself

### Update

Here's a fiddle that seems to hit more of the actual question you were asking. http://jsfiddle.net/xZzQ9/3/

Comment: `$('#name').tooltip().show();` does not work, trying to do this with basic jQuery, no libraries for tooltips

Comment: @bobbyrne01 Not basic jQuery, this appears to be jQuery UI?